# Find interpolation polynomial of different polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, numerical-methods

I try to do an exercise to calculate the interpolation polynomial of degree $4$ with nodes $(-1, -1, 0, 0, 1)$ of a function

$$
f(x) = 2x^5 + \frac{13}{281}(x+1)^2 - \frac 78(x+1) + \frac 23
$$

The big prime number in the denominator clearly suggest that the solution is based on some trick simplifying the expressions. I am not interested in brut force solution.

What I've noticed is that the polynomials
$$
\frac{13}{281}(x+1)^2 - \frac 78(x+1) + \frac 23 \ \pm2x^2
$$
Interpolates $f$ in nodes $(0, 0, \pm1)$, so we get for free the values of $f[-1, 0, 0] = \frac{13}{281}+2$ and $f[0, 0, 1] = \frac{13}{281}-2$, thus also $f[-1, 0, 0, 1]=2$. However, I'm stuck on calculating $f[-, 1,-1, 0, 0, 1]$, as I don't see how to obtain $f[-1, -1, 0, 0]$. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Duplicate nodes here mean you have derivative data, right? That is, this is a polynomial with the same $f(-1),f'(-1),f(0),f'(0),f(1)$ as this one.

Comment: yes, we define the divided difference in this case as $f[x, x, \cdots_n , x] = \frac 1{n!}f^{(n)}(x)$ and the other as usual. It can also be constructed as a limit $f[x, x_n]$ for $x_n \rightarrow x$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just find the quartic interpolant at these nodes of $g(x)=2x^5$ by any method you like, and just add that to $(13/281) (x+1)^2 - 7/8(x+1) + 2/3$. That's basically the trick here, all of the stuff of degree at most $4$ that's in your starting function can just be thrown into your interpolant as is, and all you have to think about is the rest of it.

You can do that directly, or you can start with something that's not too far off. You already know how to do the former, so I'll talk about the latter. $2x^3$ already almost agrees with $2x^5$ at these nodes, it just has the wrong derivative at $-1$. So you want to add the right multiple of $(x+1)x^2(x-1)=x^4-x^2$ to get the derivative at $-1$ to become $10$ instead of $6$.

Note that the result that I'm describing doesn't produce the interpolant in Newton divided difference form, since it has this $2x^3$ term. If you need that, then I would just run the usual algorithm.

Comment: It's even easier than that. Just subtract $\ h( x)=$$\,2(x+1)^2x^2(x-1)\ $ from $\ f(x)\ $.  Since $\ h(-1)=$$\,h'(-1)=$$\,h(0)=$$\,h'(0)=$$\ h(1)=0\ $, then the values of $\ f(x)-h(x)\ $ and its derivatives coincide with those or $\ f(x)\ $ at all the required places, and $\ f(x)-h(x)\ $ has degree $4$.